# JQuery Pull <a href

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have my jQuery script pull the url from the link clicked and then insert it into my video tag. Any advice?

I've tried splicing what I get from .html(), but the quotes always screw it up.

```
<div class="binShadow">
        <div class="bin">       
            <table id="tableBin" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>location</th>
                    <th>duration</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='clip1234.mov'>Clip1234</a></td>
                        <td>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="clip456.mov">Clip456</a></td>
                        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                        <td>dr101</td>
                        <td>:60</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>
    $("#tableBin").click(function () {
            var url = $(this).html(); //Not even close to working
            var overlay = jQuery('<div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box"><video src="'+url+'"</div></div>');

            overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if I click on the cell with "Description" in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
$("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var url = $(this).attr("href");
 var overlay = jQuery('<div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box"><video src="'+url+'"</div></div>');

 overlay.appendTo(document.body);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pull the `href` directly from the context of the click:

```
$("#tableBin").on("click", "a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  url = this.href;
});
```

Comment: I love how these questions are always a race. Upvote for beating me by two seconds :)

Comment: +1 for using `this.href` instead of the unnecessary `$(this).attr("href")`.

Comment: @ENev No problem. Glad we could be of service. When you find an answer that is helpful among all of these, please mark it as the accepted answer and earn some reputation for yourself, and the author of the answer.

Comment: @MichaelMior Hey, I resemble that statement!

Comment: @MikeRobinson It's easy to fall into a pattern of using jQuery for everything (I'm certainly guilty of it myself on many occasions), but it's good to be aware of where you can use plain old JS.

Comment: @MichaelMior I agree, and I meant it as a joke. Being shown how I can do something better is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

`var url = $(this).html();` will give you a string with the html contained within the

`<a href="...">...</a>` tags. In your case, it would read something like `Clip1234`

You want to read the `href` attribute.

```
var url = this.href; //Plain old Javascript, not jQuery
```